# Trying to get text in Advanced Data Grid Cell

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid that loads data from a web service. It only loads the top level stuff and then as you click the arrows it gets that data.

All I want to do is to find out if some text is in one of the cells. I originally did this:

```
public static function assertTextInAdg(params:Object):Boolean{
    // Gets the ADG
    trace('youre in the assertTextInAdg function');
    var grid:* = FPLocator.lookupDisplayObject(params);
    trace('var grid:* = FPLocator.lookupDisplayObject(params): ' + grid);
    // Convert ADG to automation delegate to get an array of column names
    var newGrid:* = new AdvancedDataGridAutomationImpl(grid);
    trace('var newGrid:* = new AdvancedDataGridAutomationImpl(grid): ' + newGrid);
    var datas:AdvancedDataGridTabularData = newGrid.automationTabularData as AdvancedDataGridTabularData;
    trace('var datas:AdvancedDataGridTabularData = newGrid.automationTabularData as AdvancedDataGridTabularData: ' + datas);
    var columnId:Array = datas.columnNames as Array;
    trace('var columnId:Array = datas.columnNames as Array: ' + columnId);
    // Convert ADG data to an array of rows
    var gridView:HierarchicalCollectionView = grid.dataProvider as HierarchicalCollectionView;
    trace('var gridView:HierarchicalCollectionView = grid.dataProvider as HierarchicalCollectionView: ' + gridView);
    var gridData:HierarchicalData = gridView.source as HierarchicalData;
    trace('var gridData:HierarchicalData = gridView.source as HierarchicalData: ' + gridData);
    var gridArrayColl:ArrayCollection = gridData.source as ArrayCollection;
    trace('var gridArrayColl:ArrayCollection = gridData.source as ArrayCollection: ' + gridArrayColl);
    var gridArray:Array = gridArrayColl.source as Array;
    trace('var gridArray:Array = gridArrayColl.source as Array: ' + gridArray);
    var validator:String = params.validator;
    trace('var gridArray:Array = gridArrayColl.source as Array: ' + validator);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < gridArray.length; i++) {
        for (var j:int = 0; j < columnId.length; j++) {
            if (gridArray[i][columnId[j]] == validator) { return true; }
        }
    }

    throw new Error("Validator not found in ADG.");

}
```

This works if the data is provided from the code, but now I am trying the same thing with the data being provided from a server and the traces come out like this:

```
youre in the assertTextInAdg function
var grid:* = FPLocator.lookupDisplayObject(params):           companyDashboard.dashboardCanvas.dashboardGrid
var newGrid:* = new AdvancedDataGridAutomationImpl(grid): [object AdvancedDataGridAutomationImpl]
var datas:AdvancedDataGridTabularData = newGrid.automationTabularData as AdvancedDataGridTabularData: [object AdvancedDataGridTabularData]
var columnId:Array = datas.columnNames as Array: @objectName,@customObjectType,@owner,@value0,@value1,@icon1,@value2,@icon2,@value3,@icon3,@value4,@icon4,@value5,@value6,@icon6,empty
var gridView:HierarchicalCollectionView = grid.dataProvider as HierarchicalCollectionView: [object HierarchicalCollectionView]
var gridData:HierarchicalData = gridView.source as HierarchicalData: [object HierarchicalData]
var gridArrayColl:ArrayCollection = gridData.source as ArrayCollection: null
```

And then it fails, because it can't get the source, I think. I am completely open to other strategies and I have been stuck on this problem for 10 days now. This seems like it would be relatively easy. Thanks in advance for any input.

** UPDATE **

I have been going down a slightly different route. I am now trying to iterate through the HierarchicalCollectionView with a cursor. This seems to work. But, when I get the node I can't do anything useful with it... I have been looking for examples but so far they all stop at the point of getting the node. Which means this is a stupid question I know.

```
 public static function assertTextInAdg(params:Object):Boolean{
    // Gets the ADG
    trace('youre in the assertTextInAdg function');
    var grid:* = FPLocator.lookupDisplayObject(params);
    trace('var grid:* = FPLocator.lookupDisplayObject(params): ' + grid);
    var adgData:* = grid.hierarchicalCollectionView;
    trace('var adgData:* = grid.hierarchicalCollectionView: ' + adgData);
    trace('AdgData.length() = ' + adgData.length);
    var cursor:* = adgData.createCursor();
    while(!cursor.afterLast) {
        var node:Object = cursor.current;
        cursor.moveNext();
 }
```

This is the trace() output:

```
youre in the assertTextInAdg function
var grid:* = FPLocator.lookupDisplayObject(params):     testApp.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.Panel5.myADG
var adgData:* = grid.hierarchicalCollectionView: [object HierarchicalCollectionView]
AdgData.length() = 8
node.getData: undefined
constructor: [class Object]
hasRoot: undefined
length: undefined
openNodes: undefined
prototype: undefined
showRoot: undefined
source: undefined
node.getData: undefined
constructor: [class Object]
hasRoot: undefined
length: undefined
openNodes: undefined
prototype: undefined
showRoot: undefined
source: undefined
node.getData: undefined
constructor: [class Object]
hasRoot: undefined
length: undefined
openNodes: undefined
prototype: undefined
showRoot: undefined
source: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using selenium and FlexPilot this is how I am checking for a text in a grid

```
selenium.flexAssertProperty("id=MyAppInFlex", "chain=id:userGrid/name:AdvancedListBaseContentHolder*/name:AdvancedListBaseContentHolder*, validator=text|Maria Marcano");
```

I have some blog post with information about Selenium and FlexPilot
- http://mariangemarcano.blogspot.com/2010/08/selenium-testing-with-flex-pilot.html
- http://mariangemarcano.blogspot.com/2010/10/automating-myappinflexswf-useful.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I have a few questions though. I havent seen this syntax you're using for the validator: "validator=text|Maria Marcano" I have been using the validator only with the string, like this: "validator=Maria Marcano" what is the significance of the "text|"? Also, just to make sure I understand what this does. The flexAssertPropert would pass the test if "Maria Marcano" was visible in one of the cells of the ADG, right?

Comment: validator=text|Maria Marcano, will tell the property being access and the value being checked. I think this wont check the visibility only checks that has a property with that value.

Comment: I tried this today: flexAssertProperty chain=id:myADG, validator=text|Southwest and I get this error: [error] "text" attribute does not exist on this object. This is a screenshot of my ADG, http://imgur.com/rixUa does that make any sense to you? Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Mariange, I noticed you have your own fork of the flex-pilot library. Did you need to modify some of the code for this to work on the ADG?

Comment: No, the change I did was related to an issue when doing flexAssertProperty, and that issue was fixed.

Comment: Try recording the actions (click on Arizona and then Southwest) to see the specific chain to be access. You probably need to access the chain like this to be able to access the text property id:myADG/name:AdvancedListBaseContentHolder*/name:AdvancedListBaseContentHolder*